# AngularJS response.status -1

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

My question that when I try to use the `$http.get` for a local url `response.status` returns `200`, but when the url is external (say `http://example.com`), `response.status` returns `-1` which means the request was aborted. I read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http .

**What is not clear to me is that if this status is caused by my local server or the external server. I have spoken with the admins of the external server and they say the `CORS` is allowed on their server.

Note: I am trying to make a request from within `Wordpress` using `angular`. Does it have anything to do with the `Wordpress`?

My Code:

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://example.com"}).then(
    function mySuccess(response){
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.statusText = response.statusText;
    }, function myError(response){
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.statusText = response.statusText;
        $scope.data = response.data;
    });
```

Comment: Look in your browser's *Network* console. What request(s) are being made and what are their responses?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The problem was that I was trying to make the call by `https` to `http` which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

As Phil mentioned in the comment I checked my browser's *Network Console* and it turned out that I was trying to make the request from `https` to `http` which caused the `status code` of `-1`.

I changed my configuration back to `http` for testing purposes which resolved the issue and the call is responded with `status code` of `200`